# Не правильно работает форма в Django. Подскажите, что делаю не так

Tags: python, django, form

При загрузке страницы у меня создаются формы с label, textarea и button. Я хочу сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку запускалась функция, которая к примеру, выводит label.

Код index.html

```
{% for item in res_lst %}
<form action="" method="">
<p><label>{{ item.0 }}</label></p>
<p><textarea name="textfield", type="text", cols="90", rows="20">{{ item.1 }}</textarea></p>
<button type="button", name="{{ item.0 }}", onclick="{% clickbutton_tag item.0 %}">Копировать</button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

По методу onclick в кнопке, я планирую вызвать функцию, которая является простым тегом в django.

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag()

@register.simple_tag()
def clickbutton_tag(val):
    print(val)
```

Но при загрузке страницы, функция clickbutton_tag автоматически срабатывает, не дожидаясь нажатия на кнопку. А при клике на кнопку ничего не происходит. Вывод значения в консоль сделал просто для проверки.

Что я делаю не так? Почему сразу вызывается функция